# Where can I find the "All Privileges" link from within the user profile?

Tags: support, privileges, privileges-page

On Stack Overflow, I had to search in the FAQ to bring up the "[All Privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/privileges)" page. This page might be a bit hard for new users to find.

**Question**: Would it be possible to add a link to this page within all of the SO sites? Perhaps the reputations tab within the individual user profile section would be a good spot.

As a newer user, it'd be a nice and easy way to check on my progress towards the things I might be able to do or contribute on the site.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We already have this link. Just move your mouse over your profile name. Also from the profile page you can reach this page, by clicking on your reputation.

[image: Privilige Link]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! Missed the mouseover.

Comment: +1 for freehand arrows and circles

Comment: This answer no longer applies to the current version of Stack Exchange

Answer (score 1):

[As of the 2017 nav-bar redesign on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/343653/top-navigation-update), the link to the privileges page has been moved to the **Achievements** tab.

[image: Achievements tab]

***Note:*** As of writing this only applies to Stack Overflow. There does not appear to be any nav-bar link to the privileges page from other communities.