# Can I see my privileges on my profile?

Tags: feature-request, profile-page, privileges

I just stumbled onto the [privileges page](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/privileges) on the cooking SO site. This is a super helpful page (thank you to the creator).

Could its content be added to the [user profile page](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/182792/madcookie)? I can see it as a "tab" on the list with with summary, answers, questions, tags, etc. If there is a new tab "privileges" then it would show the content.

Another option could be to simply link to it when you are viewing the "[Reputation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/182792/madcookie?tab=reputation)" tab.

Similar questions (**updated**):

1. I see [the question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/104069/where-can-i-find-the-all-privileges-link-from-within-the-user-profile) that shows privilege on the drop-down menu. I am asking specifically about the user profile page.
2. [This question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67333/where-is-the-link-to-my-privileges-page) added a link, but Reputation numbers are linking to the reputation tab.
3. [Why is there no link to /privileges on profile page but a link in profile card?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/109424/why-is-there-no-link-to-privileges-on-profile-page-but-a-link-in-profile-card)

Comment: Related: [Why is there no link to /privileges on profile page but a link in profile card?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/109424)

Comment: Tim, the edits on that question are from Dec 2011. That doesn't see too long ago, but I don't see "privs". What is the current status?

Comment: It was just an informal suggestion that I had made at the time, I don't know whether or not they were/are considering adding it to the interface. Since this is a formal request to do so, though, hopefully they will.

Comment: If you can get to it from any page via the hover menu, I'm not sure what the utility is of adding a second link on the reputation tab of your profile

Comment: Michael, there are many links on the hover menu that double on the user profile. My thought is to make more visible.